# Javascript multiple or condition check

Tags: javascript, html

I have struck with some simple if else checking

```
var IsCompanyContacttitleUpdate = false;
var ContactStatus = -1;

if ((IsCompanyContacttitleUpdate == false) && (ContactStatus == 2 || 3 || 4)) 
{
    alert('inside if');
}
else if (IsCompanyContacttitleUpdate == false && ContactStatus == 2) {
    alert('inside else if');
}
else {
    alert('yup yup else');
}
```

In this case i expected to execute the else part. but its not fired. Please help me to solve this one... Thanks in advance 
please see the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/vuHYn/1/

Comment: Wow, really? Logical operators should be one of the first things you learn.

Comment: Anyway, the second `if` clause (`else if (IsCompanyContacttitleUpdate == false && ContactStatus == 2)`) will never be reached, because the first `if` already returns true on that condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `ContactStatus == 2 || 3 || 4` is invalid (maybe invalid is not the correct word, to be more accurate let's say that it's not doing what you think it does)

For your scenario you'll need to use

```
ContactStatus == 2 || ContactStatus == 3 || ContactStatus == 4
```

Your code could be tranlated to

```
ContactStatus == 2 || true || true
```

And this is always true.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is  (ContactStatus == 2 || 3 || 4)

the correct way should (ContactStatus == 2 || ContactStatus == 3 || ContactStatus == 4)

Comment: this because 3 is considered as a boolean true, because is not 0
and your expressions will evaluate as (ContactStatus==2 || true || true)

Comment: oh yeah? 3? really? I thought it was0 or 1 for bool

Comment: @meda: Any number but `0` evaluates to `true`. `0` evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

`(ContactStatus == 2 || 3 || 4))`

Here is your problem. You are saying if `ContactStatus` equals 2, it is true, OR true OR true.

False = 0, True is anything not 0.

You need to rewrite that as:

`(ContactStatus == 2 || ContactStatus == 3 || ContactStatus == 4))`

It should work if you change that one thing

Answer (score 0):

Would this work? I changed the if condition from (ContactStatus == 2 || 3 || 4) to ((ContactStatus == 2) || (ContactStatus == 3) || (ContactStatus == 4)).

(ContactStatus == 2 || 3 || 4) evaluates (ContactStatus == 2); since it's true, it evaluates 3 as a condition. Since 3 is different from 0 (zero), then is results as true; and the whole OR evaluates to true. The final result is that the whole if condition is true and the "then" branch is selected.

```
var IsCompanyContacttitleUpdate = false;
var ContactStatus = 6;

if ((IsCompanyContacttitleUpdate == false) && ((ContactStatus == 2) || (ContactStatus == 3) || (ContactStatus == 4))) 
{
    alert('inside if')
} else if (IsCompanyContacttitleUpdate == false && ContactStatus == 2) {
    alert('inside else if')
} else {
    alert('yup yup else');

}
```

Comment: Always better to describe your solution, rather than make people search a block of code looking for the change that you've made